# Addition (+) of multiple tables into one (using sql server 2014, datagridview, and visual studio)

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, visual-studio-2015

I've been working on a project to pass time and I got stuck, so here's the issue. I have several tables connected to several datagridviews; however, I have one table that I want to connect to all the other tables. (Note: Im working on Visual Studio Windows.Form Pages using C#).

That is, one of the tables is called, let's say, **Chicago (columns: sales, quantity_sent, product_ID)** and the other is called **NewYork(columns: sales, quantity_sent, product_ID)**.

Now the **third table** is the **sum** of the sales and quantity sent of a specific product_ID for a specific table(Columns: Total_Sales, City_Name,Product_ID and Quantity_Sent).

What I want is to know how can I add these **Sales and Quantity_Sent** for each **product_ID** from a certain **table** AND have that table's name be entered into the column **City_Name**

**Chicago**

```
Sales   | quantity_Sent | Product_ID 
---------------------------------- 
23.5    | 20            | imp_091219 
17.6    | 13            | imp_05632 
5.0     | 0             | imp_05632
```

**NewYork**

```
Sales   |quantity_sent  |Product_ID
------------------------------------
0.6     | 2             | imp_091219
90.7    | 65            | imp_05632
8.7     | 3             | imp_091219
```

So, the result needs to be in such a manner in the **THIRD** table
**Total_Branches**

```
City_Name|Product_ID  |Sales|Quantity_Sent|Quantity_Remaining
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chicago  | imp_091219 |23.5 | 20          | (subtraction=(sales+quantity_sent) - available_stock from **each** table
Chicago  | imp_05632  |22.6 | 13          | (sub=(sales+quantity_sent) - available_stock 
Newyork  | imp_091219 |9.13 | 5           | (sub=(sales+quantity_sent) - available_stock
Newyork  | imp_05632  |90.7 | 65          | (sub=(sales+quantity_sent) - available_stock
```

Remember im using visual studio, windows.application.for, C#

Comment: You've tagged your question for both MySQL and SQL-server (Microsoft). Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 management studio

Comment: i would suggest you put your values into one table with an additional "CityName" column ... then you could just select CityName, Product_Id, Sum(Sales), Sum(QuantitySent) from ChicagoAndNewYork group by CityName, Product_Id

Comment: concerning your Quantity_Remaining column: where is Available_Stock supposed to come from?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn you have a point, I wanted to put them in one table but i was told to divide them into separate tables... ill just try to go with that, would make things much simpler for me. Thank you :)

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn the available stock is another column in each table, sorry i forgot to add it. But before I change everything all over again since i already implemented them into the wpf that im making, is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can union the two tables and group them:

```
select cityname, product_id, sum(sales), sum(quantity_sent) 
    from (select 'Chicago' as cityname, Product_Id, Sales, quantity_sent from chicago union all
        select 'NewYork' as cityname, Product_Id, Sales, quantity_sent from newyork) x
    group by cityname, product_id
```